# Hosting suggestions instead of Google App Engine

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

The problem is the following:
I made an EJB+JPA+GWT webpage which uses GWT for the visual layer, EJBs for the service layer and JPA for interacting with the database layer.

I was wondering if there was a way to host my website in the Google App Engine (GAE)
but then I learned that GAE doesn't support EJB´s, so I was wondering if anyone knew of 
a cheap solution for hosting a web page that uses GWT+GAE+JPA.

Comment: Belongs on webmasters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked.  You're looking at $40/m for a basic Tomcat instance (128M-512M RAM), to $100/m for full J2EE stack (1GB RAM).  You might be better off getting a dedicated server, which is what I have for the sort of things I can't use GAE for (things that need long-lived socket connections, for example).

Comment: im kind of new to web page hosting, do you think this is kinda a good option: [](http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/hosting.aspx?ci=22124)?  it looks cheap and it says that in extensive language support (on linux) Java is supported

Comment: The Godaddy plan uses Tomcat, which does not support EJB because Tomcat is a servlet container (for the most part), and not a full J2EE App Server.  You would need a hosting provider that uses GlassFish or JBoss.  My advice to you is to dump the EJBs. You can still use them as POJOs in App Engine.